# Best way to keep files on web server secure

Tags: linux, security, nginx, webserver

**Context:** I have some files on linux web server for example **create_db.txt**. They are using in my php scripts but now everyone can watch them by the direct link

```
http://url/create_db.txt
```

What is the right way to deny access to this files and still have opportunity to wright and read informations in them from php scripts. Thanks.

Comment: Are you using Apache as a webserver?

Comment: Thanks for answer. No, Im using nginx

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Web Applications Stack Exchange](http://webapps.stackexchange.com/), [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using `Apache` you could restrict access to specific files by adding an `.htaccess` file in the web root:

```
<Files create_db.txt>
Order allow, deny
Deny from all
</ Files>
```

The [`Files`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#files) section above would restrict access for all users to the `create_db.txt` file.

Running `nginx` the same could be achieved by adding the following to your configuration:

```
location ^~ /create_db.txt {
  deny all;
}
```

Like stated in the other answer you really should consider moving the file to a directory outside of your webroot. Of course the webserver must be able to access this folder. This can be done by setting the correct permission on the folder and perhaps by changing the owner to that of the webserver. Something like this:

```
mkdir -m 755 -p /path/outside/webroot
mv create_db.txt /path/outside/webroot
chown -R <user>:<group> /path/outside/webroot
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to never put files that should not be accessible into files in your web root. Just put them in a folder outside. If this is not possible, put them in a specific folder and deny access through `.htaccess` or whatever your webserver accepts